# How can I let a div inside a flex that has a content break take only the minimum required space?

Tags: html, css

I think it's best described by the following example (Open it in full screen and shrink the container):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  gap: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span id="left">
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBBBBBBB
  </span>
  <span id="right">
    btn
  </span>
</div>
```

I would like to have it so that the left item only takes the needed space, while trying to stay in one line. The right item should always take the same space.

Here are some images of what I mean:

[image]

to

[image]

but it should be:

[image]

(The above image was achieved with `width: min-content` on the left item, but that also always breaks the content, which I want to avoid)

I have tried around a lot with `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`, as well as `width` and `min-width`, but I could not get it to work properly.

Comment: you cannot do this